# Setting up RubyMotion app to play background audio

Tags: ios, audio, background, rubymotion

I'm new to RubyMotion, and I'm trying to figure out how to configure my application to continue to play music once the home button has been tapped and the app is moved to the background. In my Rakefile, I have:

```
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project/template/ios'

begin
  require 'bundler'
  require 'bubble-wrap'
  Bundler.require
  require 'sugarcube-classic'
rescue LoadError
end

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  app.name = 'test_music_app'
  app.frameworks << 'AVFoundation'
  app.frameworks << 'AudioToolbox'
  app.background_modes = [:audio]
end
```

And in my app_delegate.rb:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.setDelegate(self)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error:nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.setActive(true, error:nil)
```

I can't seem to find docs or Stack Overflow support for this, so any help would be great for myself as well as anyone else trying to get a RubyMotion music app up and running.

Comment: Have you tried running your App on a device? It works for me on a device but not on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MusicPlayer and Audio toolbox does not work on the Simulator.  Have you tried on a device?